# 120v 40amp water heater

Tags: electrical

I bought a point of use water heater that is 120v 40amp and has 8ga wire. If it’s asking for a 40amp connection, is it safe to run a dedicated line that only goes to the water heater by installing a 40amp breaker along with new wire that leads directly to the water heater?

Comment: Have you run a load calculation to make sure your service can handle the new load? Also, I take it your panel is something safe and sane in make? (i.e. not FPE or Zinsco)

Comment: It’s a safe model. It’s kept up to code

Answer (score 5):

That's what the installation instructions mean when they ask for a dedicated 40A circuit. Assuming that is what it lists, for continuous loads you have to derate the circuit breaker by 80% so if the unit draws 40A continuous you need a 50A circuit and matching wire.

However if you are running a new circuit anyway (and you have spare room in your panel) you may as well return that unit and replace it with a unit which takes 240V and needs only 20A circuit which will output the same heat and it will only need a cheaper 12/3 cable to connect. (or runs on a 30A circuit using 10/3 cable).

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It appears that the installation instructions are specifying 40A (meaning it likely draws 32A) so upsizing to 50A is not advisable - but both are indeed nuts (and rather hard to find breakers for) on 120V. Should be able to use 12/2 cable for 20A@240V - no neutral on a water heater, no need for 12/3.

Comment: This is just my opinion, not an answer, but I've never heard of a 40 amp 120v water heater.  Seems very inefficient.  It requires twice the size of wire, which as we all know is very expensive right now. Also, that's a large current draw on one of the hot legs. I agree with others here, return it and get a 240v WH,  much less expensive wiring and more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

### A 120V / 40A heater *is very, very unusual* - is it junk?

Heaters of this wattage are extremely common. However, **they are always sold as 240V/20A** heaters instead of 120V/40A (which is the same wattage, you notice).  This allows them to be wired with cheap 12/2 Romex instead of costly 8/2 or 6/2.

Who does not know this? The Chinese.

We've seen *[an](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BBFPLZ2K) endless [parade](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B6ZZQ41L)* of high-power products - T-shirt presses, kilns, heaters, etc. that require 40-60 amps of 110V.  It's dumb, and it seems like they're trying to trick novices into thinking since it's 110V it'll be easy.  At least, it has that effect.  The consumer struggles with it for over a month and then the Amazon return window closes, and they're stuck with it.   Very few sales lead to successful projects.

### Go for domestic-market shops, not mail order.

We recommend people never buy electrical equipment from Amazon or eBay because of all the shady stuff and trickery - Amazon is [mostly 3rd party sellers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCTiU2ZHVwI) anymore selling the cheapest crud off Alibaba.  Stick to domestic retail (or their mail-order arms e.g. homedepot.com or wickes.co.uk - beware, walmart.com mixes in Amazon Marketplace products!)

Note that you will find *a few* 120V high-power heaters; these are for RVs (and tiny houses wired like RVs) where every load is required to be 120V because of how RV parks work.  Circuits need to supply 125% of water heater load, so the max power for a 240V/20A heater is 3840W.

Comment: I thought EV chargers always came with NEMA 14-50 plugs because that’s “the RV plug” — why does an RV imply 120V loads?

Comment: @JacobKrall -- many smaller RVs use a TT-30 plug that provides 120V@30A

Comment: @JacobKrall yeah, you may drive your large RV to a park and find the only stands available are TT30 type, or visit a home and the only thing available is 120V/15-20A.  You would use an adapter that splits that to both your hots. So to minimize disruption, almost all loads are 120V. You have to be power-wise of course.